# What could cause a variable to change value?

Tags: c++, variables, memory-management

I had a phone interview with a tech giant and one of the questions was something like this:

Say you have a function and inside the function you have

```
int i = 100;
```

you do some other things in the function without touching variable i and later on you print i and you see the value is different. What could have caused the change?

I answered: some kind of memory corruption, memory overrun..etc..They didnt seem happy with the answer.Now I thought about stack pointer getting messed up. Is there anything that I'm missing ?

Comment: Tech giants usually ask you to keep the entire content of such conversations confidential, don't they?

Comment: I even wonder if you have transcribed the question correctly as it was asked or whether it was described to you adequately.

Comment: If you really couldn't touch `i` in any defined or undefined way, I suggest touching `cout`.

Answer (score 2):

Incorrectly using a single equal sign (assignment) instead of a double equal sign (comparison) in an if statement is a good way.

Comment: that involves "touching" variable i, using the OP's words.

Comment: One would *think* they were not touching the variable. ;-)  hence the tricky question.

Comment: haha i dont know if they would have accepted that but i guess it's a valid answer

Comment: I believe the interviewer was testing your debugging skills.

Answer (score 2):

You use other local `i` variable names at different scopes (e.g. in a `for` loop, deeper scope, globally declared, module/function static, member variable, ...), and so the `i` you THINK you are printing out is not the `i` you are actually printing out.

Another possibility - references.  Another variable that references `i`.

Answer (score 1):

> int i = 100

If you are defining it inside the function, it would be on STACK variable. So if by any means(.i.e. by passing the arguments which has overflown or some other local variables inside the function has overflown), it can change the value of **"i"**. This could happen because of stack overflow/corruption.

However such scenario can lead to the corruption in the stack pointer/return value of the function which would ultimately can crash/undefined behaviour your program.

Answer (score 1):

That version of `i`is completely gone when the function returns, since it was a local variable declared inside the function, so its lifetime is tied to the function. The version of `i` that is printed out *outside* of the function (afterwards) is a completely different `i`, defined before the function

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing (assuming you are referring to the same i, which means where you print the value of i is inside the same function).

```
#include <stdio.h>

void f()
{
    char buf[100];
    int i = 100;
    int j;

    for (j = 0; i <= 100; j++){
       buf[j] = 255;
    }

    printf("i=%d\n", i);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Guess what is printed?  yep. i=255.  What I'm trying to show here is that we can overrun a buffer and stuff up the content of the variables that follow.

A more subtle way of doing that is with the misuse of sizeof.

e.g.

```
  int array[100]
  sizeof array  != 100

  So you can't do
  for (i = 0; i < sizeof array; i++)  // very bad!
```

So you could see how a bug could result in buffer overrun.

However, with modern versions of gcc the above code will core dump.  Including the first one.  I had to actually compile it with the -fno-stack-protector option to get it to print a result without dumping core.  If you do the sizeof one it'll dump core straight away.

Answer (score 1):

> I answered: some kind of memory corruption, memory overrun..etc.

Pretty reasonable start.

"without touching variable i" is a bit vague as obvious `i` is being touched, so we're left to guess what kind of touching isn't obvious enough to count as touching.  Perhaps:

***Undefined behaviour***: all bets are off....

***References and pointers***: if a non-`const` reference or pointer to `i` was created, `i` may have been modified indirectly.  It's also possible that a dangling pointer to that stack address (but not "your" `i`) was given to some async interrupt or other thread, and that your `i` may be modified through its use).

***Interrupt processing***: not commonly a concern for application code, but if you've writing your own interrupt handlers - or trying some alpha/beta ones - they might be accidentally screwing with your stack or even corrupting the register that the compiler expects `i` to be available in

***Inline assembly language***: if the compiler's loaded `i` into a register, and you do something with the register in some inline assembly for which the compiler doesn't push/save and pop/restore the value, `i` may appear to have changed when printed

An ***off-by-one error*** could cause the problem:

```
char s[3];
int i = 100;
... do something that loads text into c that might not be terminated ...
s[sizeof s] = '\0'; // "ensure termination" / actually off by one
```

Admittedly this is kind of covered by "overrun", though it's not the "cool" kind ala `fscanf("%s", &s);` that could go arbitrarily far past `s`.

Other thoughts:

- threading is potentially relevant as a way statements not under scrutiny may have screwed with `i`, but each thread has a separate stack so it'd take major corruption/undefined behaviour
- "later on you print i" - I'd assume it's not what they're looking for, but there's a class of ways in which this might be stuffed up: printing in hex and *thinking* the value 64 is different from the expected 100 decimal, printing `i` from another scope), "interference" from other print statements (potentially in other threads) e.g. following print of "0" makes `i` seem to be "1000"